# Google SMTP relay sending limits

Tags: gmail, smtp

I'm considering using Google Apps for email with my company domain and for sending emails to customers from my website using SMTP. On [Google's website](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2956491) it says the following:

> **Limits for registered Google Apps users**
>
> A registered Google Apps user cannot relay messages to more than 2,000 recipients per day.
>
> **Limits per domain**
>
> Per-domain sending limits are determined by the
>   number of users in your Google Apps account. There are two per-domain
>   limits:
>
> - **The maximum number of recipients allowed per domain per day is approximately 130 times the number of users in your Google Apps account.**
> - The maximum number of recipients allowed per domain in a 10 minute window is approximately 9 times the number of users in your Google Apps account.
>
> Additionally, the maximum number of recipients allowed
>   per domain per day for accounts not yet paid for during the first
>   month of service is 100.

If I'm a single user, with a single domain, then does that mean I can only email 130 people a day using SMTP?  That limit seems low.

Comment: I don't know this option, but there are services for e-mailing customers in a relatively safe way. Google may have another option, but there is also something like constant contact and others to check out. Have you researched other options? This one does not seem too flexible to me.

Comment: I do know of other options like Constant Contact and Campaign Monitor, but those can get a bit too expensive if you're sending out lots of email. I was hoping Google would allow more emails for their $5/mth plan.

Comment: I run my own e-mail server so I do not know these options but I am getting ready to look into them for Mom's antique business. How about GoDaddy? Anything there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**If I'm a single user, with a single domain, then does that mean I can only email 130 people a day using SMTP? That limit seems low.**

No, that means you can email as many users, but it should be limited to 130 different domains. This isn't a problem if you want to send mostly emails to popular domains such as @gmail @outlook @yahoo and similar. If you, however, email a lot of different business clients who most of the time have custom domains, then this limit imposes that you shouldn't be using gmail for such things.

If you want to look for alternatives, then there are good and well priced options by service providers such as Mandrill, MailGun, Sendgrid etc. They specialise in email sending relay and only limit on the amount of emails sent. Having personal experience with Mandrill, they give you 12k emails per month for free, while additional will cost around $0.2 per 1000, so this is something to consider. Other providers will be priced on a similar level.

Comment: Mandrill looks perfect. Didn't even know about them. It's actually only $0.20 per additional 1,000. Thank you for telling me about this!

Comment: Fixed the typo regarding the price, thanks and good luck!

Comment: "limited to 130 different domains" - In the Google docs quoted above, "130" would seem to relate the "number of _recipients_ per domain". The number of domains is not stated.